# Check whether an HTML element is editable or not using JS

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Using JS, how can we find whether we can type into a html element or not. I am trying by comparing ".tagName" to "INPUT" or "TEXTAREA" but it fails to differentiate between a regular input text/email element and a radio-button  or a submit-button.

I also tried with ".isContentEditable" but when the element is "inherited" then I am unable to differentiate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For inputs and textareas, check `tagName` and `type`, not forgetting newer HTML5 input types such as `email`. Here's a snippet from my code for testing this on an element stored in a variable called `el`:

```
var nodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
if (el.nodeType == 1 && (nodeName == "textarea" ||
    (nodeName == "input" && /^(?:text|email|number|search|tel|url|password)$/i.test(el.type)))) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

For other elements, the [`isContentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.isContentEditable) property works in all cases and should only ever return a Boolean, never a string such as `"inherit"`.

Finally, there is the possibility that the whole document has been made editable using the [`document.designMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.designMode) property, in which case `document.designMode` will have the string value `"on"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typescript version.

```
function isEditableElement(el: EventTarget) {
  if (el instanceof HTMLElement && el.isContentEditable) return true;
  if (el instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types
    if (/|text|email|number|password|search|tel|url/.test(el.type || '')) {
      return !(el.disabled || el.readOnly);
    }
  }
  if (el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) return !(el.disabled || el.readOnly);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@percy507 there is a typo.
`if (/|text|email|numb` -> `if (/text|email|numb`

```js
function isEditableElement(el: EventTarget) {
  if (el instanceof HTMLElement && el.isContentEditable) return true;
  if (el instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types
    if (/text|email|number|password|search|tel|url/.test(el.type || '')) {
      return !(el.disabled || el.readOnly);
    }
  }
  if (el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) return !(el.disabled || el.readOnly);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the read only property.

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp :

```
document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: its not working, "readOnly" value for a "submit" button is false